# ListSliceDensityPlot with CSV

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I am trying to plot a 4 column (CSV) x,y,z,f file with the ListSliceDensityPlot function for z = 1
But it does not work

```
data = Import["4column.txt", "CSV"]

ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"ZStackedPlanes", {1}}, DataRange -> {{0, 2}, {2, 90}, {1*10^-11, 3*10^-11}}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

I get an empty graph

[image]

First lines of the data file in case it helps:

0.0,46.0,1.0,1.0292540460153382e-11

0.02,46.0,1.0,1.0343595185370281e-11

0.04,46.0,1.0,1.0497959721450607e-11

0.06,46.0,1.0,1.0759270651155357e-11

0.08,46.0,1.0,1.1133712938910363e-11

Comment: Please post the csv file in  some place and add the link. The problem seems that the Z values is too small to show.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not deliver the data, I create some data arbitrarily. Note that the data has the format: {{x1,y1,z1,f[x1,y1,z1]}{x2,y2,z2,f[x2,y2,z2]},...}:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2}, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, {z, -n, n}], 2];
```

Then with this data:

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"ZStackedPlanes", 1}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]